# Difference between two interior lines of a triangle

Tags: contest-math, triangles

[image]

Here, $AB = 2017 \text{ units}$.

$O$ is mid-point on $AB$.

$D$ is such an interior point to $\Delta ABC$, so that $\angle DAP = \angle DBQ$.

Now,  ***What is $(OP - OQ) $ ?***

So far, I have proceeded to the point that $\Delta APD$ and $\Delta BQD$ are similar.

Answer (score 0):

The value $OP-OQ=0$, regardless of $AB$'s length. 
Using [median's length formula](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Length_of_Median_of_Triangle) in $\triangle{APB}$ and $\triangle{AQB}$, is suffices to prove that 
$$\frac{AP^2 + BP^2}{2} - \frac{AB^2}{4} = \frac{AQ^2 + BQ^2}{2} - \frac{AB^2}{4}$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow AP^2 + BP^2 = AQ^2 + BQ^2$$

Using [pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem), we can write $AP^2 = AD^2 - PD^2$, and $ BQ^2 = BD^2- DQ^2$.
Writing $BP^2$ and $AQ^2$ using [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) in $\triangle{BDP}$ and $\triangle{ADQ}$, it only remains to show 
$$BD\times DP\times\cos(\widehat{BDQ}) = AD\times DQ\times\cos(\widehat{ADQ})$$
Which is obvious from $\triangle{APD} \sim \triangle{BDQ}$.

[image]